# Make only one bootstrap column pop below other three on small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

Here is a screen shot of my footer when on the desktop...

[image]

When I shrink the screen I get this messy lay out...

[image]

Yuck, I would ideally like to have the far right column pop below the other three like this:

[image]

I have tried a number of things to no avail... here is my grid layout at the moment... I can work out how to specifically get the for right col to pop below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        foo
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        baz
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        qux
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you pare your code down to just the specific area of the page you're trying to fix?

Comment: Sure thing! One sec..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    foo
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
        baz
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        qux
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you'll want to set the bottom div to be `col-xs-12` in some way, since they want that whole section to span the entire width.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond... for the record I had to add col-xs-12 to the last column to make things work as expected.

Comment: Haha, the timing!

Comment: @MattD No need to state `col-xs-12` for the last column, because it's stated by default. if you'll make an effort to read bootstrap docs carefully, you'll find out that.

Comment: Also you can read an amazing fact over there: **Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.** Thus, for our case `"col-md-4 col-xs-6"` = `"col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"`, as well as `"col-md-4"` is equal to `"col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"`

Answer (score 1):

Use all of them... col-xs, col-sm, col-md & col-lg...
Its xtra small, small, medium and large view

And then calculate.. Each row has 12 columns in bootstraps grid system.

Like: 
4 - 4 - 4 or,
4 - 2 - 2 - 4 or,
8 - 2 - 2 or whatever you want ;)

For example: If u want to use two divs with col-lg-6 u will have 2 columns in one row in largeview.. If you set them both to 12 in sm you will get them as one column in two rows in the small view.